# hide certain components on multiple routes angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im trying to hide a component when certain routes match, I've got it working with 1 route but if I do multiple it doesnt work

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template:  `
    <app-header *ngIf="!_router.url.includes('account', 'admin', 'app')"></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer *ngIf="!_router.url.includes('app', 'account', 'admin')"></app-footer>
`
})
export class RootComponent {
    router: string;

    constructor(
        public _router: Router
    ) {
        this.router = _router.url;
    }
}
```

now this isnt working but if I only have one word in the `includes()` it works is there any other way of doing this??

**edit**

I have tried to do this...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template:  `
        <app-header *ngIf="!hasMatches('app', 'account', 'admin')"></app-header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <app-footer *ngIf="!hasMatches('account', 'admin', 'app')"></app-footer>
    `
})
export class RootComponent {
    router: string;

    constructor(
        public _router: Router
    ) {
        this.hasMatches();
        this.router = _router.url;
    }

    private hasMatches(...values: string[]): boolean {
        let matchFound = false;

        for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (this.router.indexOf(values[i]) > -1) {
                matchFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return matchFound;
    }

    // isPage(): boolean {
    //     const re = /^\/(account|admin|app)$/;
    //     return !re.test(this.router.url);
    // }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use indexOf(). The hasMatches()-method below is capable of handling any number of arguments you want.

HTML

```
<app-header *ngIf="!hasMatches('account', 'admin', 'app')"></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer *ngIf="!hasMatches('app', 'account', 'admin')"></app-footer>
```

TS

```
routeUrl: string;

constructor(
    public _router: Router
) {
    // subscribe to the router events in order to always get the current url
    this._router.events.subscribe(() => this.routeUrl = this._router.url ); 
}

private hasMatches(...values: string[]): boolean {
    let matchFound: boolean = false;

    // check for null or undefined first
    if(this.routeUrl){ 
        for (i=0; i<values.length; i++){
             if(this.routeUrl.indexOf(values[i]) > -1){
                matchFound = true;
                break;
             }
        }        
    }

    return matchFound;
}
```

Comment: Im getting indexOf does not exist on type router

Comment: But router is supposed to be a string? Has the field 'url' a toString()-method? Can you check this, please?

Comment: sorry your right I accidentally commented out the router = string;

Comment: Please see updated question and let me know if I have done anything wrong

Comment: This is strange. It should work out. Can you please apply console.log(matchFound); directly before return matchFound? I'd like to know the result of both runs.

Comment: in the terminal im getting false but im also getting a bunch of errors that say.. Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Comment: Does it ever stop? Do you get the result you want?

Comment: Hey I figured out what the problem is.. I updated your answer with what I did to get it working.. please let me know if  you see any issues, but this is working for me

Comment: Perfect. Your edit is no problem to me and the added subscription was indeed the missing peace I did not see! Well done. ;) -- I just adjusted the wording of you comments a little, if this is okay to you. And I switched the order of the null-/undefined-check and the for loop. This way you will never enter the loop if router is null or undefined. -- I'm glad to hear that I could help you. :)

Comment: the variable "router: string" should be renamed to "routeUrl: string" so to be easily understandable   (Updated answer to match)